# Notifications to the right when clicked on icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I m trying to achieve this as seen in the first image. There is this small icon representing number of icons: For eg. 3

[image: before icon click]

Then once the user clicks on the icon I need to show the messages as below :

[image: a busy cat]

Hence I tried to do some experiments on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkvirendra/e75Zx/5/). But couldn't figure out how to achieve it.
Since I m a newbie to the world of Front End Development.
So can anyone please suggest me, what should I do ?

Edit : Is there a Jquery plugin available that can help me with this ?

Comment: Remove `position: fixed`

Comment: Updated the Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bkvirendra/e75Zx/1/

Comment: So you have just fixed it yourself.

Comment: And also added the <ul> tags http://jsfiddle.net/bkvirendra/e75Zx/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/e75Zx/4/

PS: You should use a list (`<ul>`) for menus and nav bars like in this purpose.

Comment: +1 for the answer; however, I disagree with the `UL` statement.